# Meaning of "in that sometimes" in "There's a chance for a splendid fortune in that sometimes."

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

> "Oh, good-bye, our dreams!" said Sir Huon. "It's neither sceptre, sword, nor plough!
>   Maybe yet it's a bookful of learning, bound with iron clasps.
>   There's a chance for a splendid fortune **in that sometimes**.

This is from "[Rewards and Fairies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewards_and_Fairies)" by Kipling.
I can not understand the meaning of "in that sometimes".

Comment: *Sometimes* is an adverb here, meaning *on some occasions*. It could be moved and the meaning might be clearer to you: "There is sometimes a chance for a splendid fortune in that", where *that* stands for *a bookful of learning*.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning becomes clearer if you add the implied comma:

> There's a chance for a splendid fortune in that, sometimes.

As @StoneyB said, it's an adverb here, meaning "on some occasions".